# ConnectionRefusedError: WinError 10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: python, llama

When I try to upload a file to localGPT SOURCE_DOCUMENTS folder, it shows an error like the message below.

(localGPT) PS C:\source\localGPT\localGPTUI> **python .\localGPTUI.py**

```
[2023-12-19 17:55:10,814] ERROR in app: Exception on / [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\envs\localGPT\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3\envs\localGPT\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 96, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\intel\anaconda3\envs\localGPT\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 86, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=WinError+10061 In any case, your question lacks a [mcve]. Just in case, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not a bug or issue, I checked another API console interface.

The process cannot access the file because **it is being used by another process.**
So I close that file and try again. it works to upload.

**(localGPT) PS C:\source\localGPT> python run_localGPT_API.py**

```
load INSTRUCTOR_Transformer
max_seq_length  512
llama_model_loader: loaded meta data with 19 key-value pairs and 291 tensors from ./models\models--TheBloke--Llama-2-7b-Chat-GGUF\snapshots\191239b3e26b2882fb562ffccdd1cf0f65402adb\llama-2-7b-chat.Q4_K_M.gguf (version GGUF V2)
...
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [19/Dec/2023 17:58:33] "POST /api/save_document HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Error: C:\source\localGPT/DB\chroma.sqlite3 - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```